# Elasticsearch order by a certain field value first

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to apply a certain sort to a query, it should sort my documents by a single value first then all the others. I need to achieve something like the ORDER BY CASE WHEN in MySQL, but I couldn't find how to do it.

Each element in the index in Elastic has the following structure:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "name": "Title",
    "categories": ["A", "B", "C"],
    "price": 100,
    "city": "London",
    "country": "United Kingdom",
    "status": 1
}
```

I do the following query:

```
{
    "fields": [],
    "sort": [{"price": {"order": "asc"}}],
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "status:1 AND country:'United Kingdom'"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "id",
                "size": 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So by sorting the column `city` with value "Liverpool" first and considering the following example:

```
{"id": 1, "name": "Test", "categories": ["A", "B", "C"], "price": 100, "city": "London", "country": "United Kingdom", "status": 1 }
{"id": 2, "name": "Sample", "categories": ["A", "D", "F"], "price": 200, "city": "Manchester", "country": "United Kingdom", "status": 1 }
{"id": 3, "name": "Title", "categories": ["X", "Y", "Z"], "price": 1000, "city": "Liverpool", "country": "United Kingdom", "status": 1 }
```

I expect to have as output the following id: 3, 1, 2.

How can I change my query to obtain this behaviour?

**UPDATE**: The version is 1.7.2

Comment: What would be the `ORDER BY CASE WHEN` in your case?

Comment: Did you finally find a solution for your case?

Answer (score 10):

You should use ["_script"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) for 1.7 version. Try this:

1.7:

```
"query" : {
    ....
},
"sort" : {
    "_script" : {
        "script" : "doc['city'].value == 'Liverpool' ? 1 : 0",
        "type" : "number",
        "order" : "desc"
    },
    "example_other_field_order":"asc",
    "next_example_field_order":"asc"
}
```

For latest version of elasticsearch (>= 5.5) check [this doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html).

Answer (score 1):

Actually you want to sort by city first then by price ? 
The key point is the type of "city" filed , it's string (maybe you set analyzed ? ) not integer. So if you set analyzed on filed "city", you'd better add a property named "raw" without analyzed, then you can sort by "city: first .

Try the following:

```
 "sort": [{"city.raw": {"order": "asc"}},{"price": {"order": "asc"}}],
```

You can visit https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-fields.html for more help.

Otherwise, if you only need to make the "Liverpool" city first then other cities when search and sort , you should use boost feature in your query. Visit https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/multi-query-strings.html for more help.