# how set a specific order by field of elasticsearch response?

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I use the elasticsearch 1.7 and I have a lot document of devices with the next structure

```
        {  
      "color": "Dorado",
      "colorCss": "#B99919",
      "colorSE": "DORADO",
      "dAuditivaHabla": true,
      "dMotriz": true,
      "dVisual": true,
      "esBuenFin": false,
      "esFechaEspecial1": false,
      "esFechaEspecial2": false,
      "esFechaEspecial3": false,
      "esHotMonday": false,
      "esHotSale": false,
      "esLanzamiento": false,
      "esNuevo": false,
      "esOferta": false,
      "esPreventa": false,
      "esProximamente": false,
      "esquema": "pre",
      "fechagenerica": "2018-08-22",
      "fechagenericaini": "2018-08-21",
      "fechavigencianuevo": "2018-08-04",
      "fechavigenciaprox": "2018-07-26",
      "fechavigenciaproximo": "2018-07-27",
      "historico": false,
      "idcomp": "4035-70010415-9",
      "idequipo": 4035,
      "idequipocolor": 2,
      "idequipover": 193,
      "idplan": 0,
      "idplanversion": 0,
      "idpvev": "193pre",
      "idtiporegion": 1,
      "idtipoterminal": 1,
      "marca": {
        "id": 34,
        "nombre": "Apple"
      },
      "marcaSE": "APPLE",
      "modelo": "iPhone 7",
      "modeloSE": "IPHONE7",
      "nombreOrden": "IPHONE 7",
      "orden": 0,
      "plazo": 0,
      "posicionEtiqueta": "0",
      "precio": 7999,
      "region": 9,
      "sapDefault": "1",
      "sapid": 0,
      "SAP": 70010415,
      "tipoCapacidad": "32 GB",
      "tipoCapfiltro": "GB",
      "versionSO": "10"
    }
```

Currently I order these documents by various fields, but now I have a new requirement and I need to place some documents at the top of the answer, I specifically need to place the documents with SAP 80010304 74302933 and 97846323 at the top of the answer. So if I have these SAP's

80010304
74302933
97846323
99949233
16773043
79820934

I need that Elasticsearch to answer me always the first 3 in the first 3 positions, regardless of the sorting that is applied later

I found this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45281512/8679337

When I apply a Short Script in the field **SAP** this not works

```
    curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/planesequiposversiones/_search' -d '{
         "query": {
              ...
          },
         "sort" : {
              "_script" : {
                  "script" : "doc['"'"'SAP'"'"'].value == '"'"'80010304'"'"' ? 1 : 0",
                  "type" : "number",
                  "order" : "desc"
              }
           }
        }'
```

The response is

```
        {
      "took": 32,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
        "total": 236,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
          {
            "_index": "planesequiposversiones",
            "_type": "planesequiposversiones",
            "_id": "193pre",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
              ...
              "marca": {
                "id": 34,
                "nombre": "Apple"
              },
              "SAP": 70010415,
              ...
            },
            "sort": [
              0.0
            ]
          },
          {
            "_index": "planesequiposversiones",
            "_type": "planesequiposversiones",
            "_id": "189pre",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
              ...
              "marca": {
                "id": 1,
                "nombre": "Alcatel"
              },
              "SAP": 70010426,
              ...
            },
            "sort": [
              0.0
            ]
          },
          {
            "_index": "planesequiposversiones",
            "_type": "planesequiposversiones",
            "_id": "192pre",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
              ...
              "marca": {
                "id": 34,
                "nombre": "Apple"
              },
              "SAP": 80010304,
              
            "sort": [
              0.0
            ]
           }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

the field **sort** of elasticsearch is 0.0  and the fiel **SAP** 80010304 is in the 15th position

when I change the **SAP** field from Script to **marca.id** the **sort** field returns with 1.0 regardless of **marca.id**

```
        curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/planesequiposversiones/_search' -d '{
         "sort" : {
              "_script" : {
                  "script" : "doc['"'"'marca.id'"'"'].value == '"'"'34'"'"' ? 1 : 0",
                  "type" : "number",
                  "order" : "desc"
              }
           }
        }'
```

response

```
        {
      "took": 32,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
        "total": 236,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
          {
            "_index": "planesequiposversiones",
            "_type": "planesequiposversiones",
            "_id": "193pre",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
              ...
              "marca": {
                "id": 34,
                "nombre": "Apple"
              },
              "SAP": 70010415,
              ...
            },
            "sort": [
              1.0
            ]
          },
          {
            "_index": "planesequiposversiones",
            "_type": "planesequiposversiones",
            "_id": "189pre",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
              ...
              "marca": {
                "id": 1,
                "nombre": "Alcatel"
              },
              "SAP": 70010426,
              ...
            },
            "sort": [
              1.0
            ]
          },
          {
            "_index": "planesequiposversiones",
            "_type": "planesequiposversiones",
            "_id": "192pre",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
              ...
              "marca": {
                "id": 34,
                "nombre": "Apple"
              },
              "SAP": 80010304,
              
            "sort": [
              1.0
            ]
           }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Please help me I dont understand how to set a specific device at the firts position

Comment: Does all doc contain SAP field?

Comment: Yes, all documents contain SAP field, but I dont want a order by ASC or DESC I just need set a some docs with specific SAP at the response top

Comment: What is the mapping for SAP field?

Comment: "SAP":{ "type":"long"}