# Combining search engine and database

Tags: database, search-engine

If I have search engine database which have a lot of records (id and keywords associated with that id), when given input (list of keywords), will output list of ids and the ranking

```
database:
id1     keyword1 keyword2 ... keyword9
id2     keyword4 keyword7 ... keyword10
id3     keyword5 keyword6 ... keyword12
...
id99999 keyword15 keyword6 ... keyword19

input:
keyword8 keyword9

output:
id1      0.994
id2125   0.841
...
id84512  0.342
```

Then to show it to the user, we would do the query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE id IN ('id1','id2125',...,'id5127') 
         -- ^ only need to bind first 20 ids
         --   from search engine result
         --   and 21st to 40th ids for next page
         --   and so on
```

But when user pick choose to show it sorted by lowest price, we would have to do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE id IN (/* a very very long list */)
         -- ^ all the ids from search engine result
ORDER BY current_price
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

That potentially be slow right? (would not scale if we have for example 10k ids from search result).

We could reduce the argument binding length/passing/transfer by inserting into another table (eg. `search_results` table) then do `WHERE IN (SELECT)` query (so search with same keyword or the next page would be faster):

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM search_results WHERE search_id = ?)
ORDER BY current_price
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

But with this we would also have to insert large numbers of ids into `search_results` table

```
INSERT INTO search_results(search_id,id) VALUES(...,'id1'),(...,'id2125'),(...,'id2156'),... -- and so on

-- or in PostgreSQL which support array data type
INSERT INTO search_results(search_id,ids) VALUES(...,{'id1','id2125','id2156',...,'id5126'});
-- then the query above would be:
-- WHERE id = ANY(SELECT ids FROM search_results WHERE search_id = ?)
```

The question:

1. What's better way to do this if any?
2. How people in amazon or any other online shop do this kind of case (what search engine and/or database combination they use) or entirely using something else?

Comment: There are an essentially unlimited number of tech combinations that could be used for this (and some may be entirely internal). ElasticSearch or similar is often used for massive search spaces, but that's one choice of dozens.

Comment: @DaveNewton ah right, elasticsearch can do the ordering/sorting by other column so there would not be such problem like in my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39762238/elasticsearch-order-by-a-certain-field-value-first

Comment: and apparently other search engines also support multiple columns filtering and ordering, so not just id and keywords https://manual.manticoresearch.com/Quick_start_guide
I would use this instead of https://github.com/go-ego/riot